# SSL通信における共通鍵の管理方法について

Tags: apache, ssl, https

クライアントとサーバで同一の共通鍵を生成するところまでは理解しましたが、
その後、「クライアントと共通鍵との対応関係」を

1. サーバのどこが
2. どう管理するか

を知りたいです。

以下であっていますか？

1. Apacheであれば、mod_ssl
2. クライアントの「IPアドレス」と「ポート番号」ごとに対応する共通鍵を保管する

Comment: タイトルの「公開鍵暗号方式」では共通鍵は利用しないはずですので、「SSL通信における共通鍵の管理方法について」が正しいタイトルですかね？

Comment: 失礼しました、おっしゃるとおりですね。変更しておきます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

共有鍵はSSL/TLSの接続毎に生成されるので、おそらくmod_ssl が管理しているメモリ内にだけ存在します。Apacheのプロセスが終了するときは接続も終了するので、とくにディスクに保存する必要はありません。

同一のクライアントとの通信でも、接続が別ならば共有鍵も別のものが生成されて使われます。

Comment: やはりそういう理解でよいですよね、ご回答いただきありがとうございます！